# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 9205760 into shape (2500)

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create the windows of 2500 size from my actual array size `9205760`. Also this array size will differ as per the new records I test.

What I want is, it automatically adjust the last window and keep all remaining windows 2500 size. How to do ?

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(np.random.randint(1,5,9205760))
print(len(arr))

sig_frames=np.reshape(arr,(-1,10*250))
```

Error

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 9205760 into shape (2500)
```

Comment: Adjusting the size of an array is a poorly defined topic.  Obviously you can take a subset of the values via indexing.  But usually people want to retain some sort of property of the array. If the arrays is derived from an image, then use image software to resize it.

Answer (score 0):

9205760 doesn't divide by 2500 without reminder, which is why you can't cast it into that shape. If you need the 2500 dimensions, make sure that the data you have is a multiple of that number.

Comment: Yes it does not divide 2500 without reminder. It is possible that I skip the reminder value and consider only possible 2500 windows

Comment: You could just do `new_arr = arr[:9205000]` and reshape that